# Upgrading From Ubuntu 18.04.2 to 19.04 Using DVD

Tags: apt, upgrade, data-recovery, livedvd, add-apt-repository

I hope someone can help.

My SSD hard drive containing the OS failed but I was able to rescue most of my data using ddrescue. I restored the data for my old Ubuntu 18.04.2 (Bionic Beaver) to the partition a new larger hard drive and also installed the new Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) on another partition and made the computer successful dual boot. The gui boot no longer works on my old installation so I set the default login to console and am I now able to login to the old operating system.

Many software updates were waiting for me once I logged into the old installation, but the package manager (apt, apt-get, and aptitude) is all messed up with many corrupted files and I can't get it work no matter what I do. Now I am no longer interested in repairing it because I  realize there are probably more corrupted system software files, such as my video driver, that prevents me from logging in gui mode. Since package management is probably beyond repair, upgrading Ubuntu 18.04.2 (Bionic Beaver) from within the installation via command line is impossible.

So this is the current situation of my old installation of Ubuntu 18.04.2 (Bionic Beaver) server:

- It contains Ubuntu Studio and can be logged into at the console as well as over the network via ssh and webmin

  - Some servers work, ssh and webmin, but others fail, such as mythtv backend  ( I'm missing all my favorite TV shows, no soap operas for my wife !!!)
- my home directory /home was mounted on a partition of another hard drive and was undamaged by the failure of SSD hard drive

  - All my normal user desktop launchers appear on my desktop when the partition containing the home  directories is properly mounted on the new Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo), but since the home directory is mounted from a different hard drive and the software isn't installed on the new distribution, of course, most software doesn't work
- fsck disk check finds no errors on the restored partition containing Ubuntu 18.04.2 (Bionic Beaver)
- there may be about a hundred specialized applications from various PPAs installed on my damaged OS, so I want to avoid having to download them again,  or worse, having to reconfigure them to work correctly on a new installation. Example, I can TV watch recordings anywhere in the world through my mythtv server using my cell phone on either local wifi or cellular data, but I don't remember how I did it

  - trying to add so many specialized applications and servers to a new installation of Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) and trying  to configure them is extremely impractical ... I really don't want to do it  !!!

That is why I want to upgrade in place using installation media, not over the network, so that most applications and system software are upgraded without loss of settings and configurations (hoping not too many configuration files were damaged on the dead hard drive),  most of which I have forgotten. I want to upgrade the Ubuntu 18.04.2 (Bionic Beaver) to Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) using the DVD / ISO I downloaded already.  I remember years ago, an option to do exactly that from the installation DVD but I can't find it anymore. How do I  do that?

Thanks in advance
 -

Comment: I think this is a bad idea. While it is possible to kind of "upgrade" from a DVD by installing to the same partition without formatting, the DVD won't have "a hundred specialized applications from various PPAs", so they'll end up broken and incompatible with the new system. Also, so called "my drivers" won't be there, unless you have them ready for the new system. To summarize, it is ok to use a DVD, but it won't solve any of the problems listed above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I agree that "DVD upgrade" is less than ideal. After DVD upgrade, I will have to add back all the PPAs and reinstall broken software, but with so many packages to deal with, I still think my approach, as ugly as it is, it is the most practical solution. Yes, months from now, I will try to run an application just to discover that it is corrupt because I didn't reinstall it, but I don't remember all the applications I installed and a list of installed packages include dependencies, thousounds of files, makes my head spin! so how do I upgrade with the DVD?

Comment: Years ago, older versions of the install media had an option to upgrade exisiting installations in place, but now I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called Repair Ubuntu that can be accessed from the Boot Menu while a Bootable USB or DVD is connected. As you said GUI Login is no longer working, have you checked the following link, [Help Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)? How about that option?

Moreover, there is no such thing called Disco Dingo is the Latest and Bionic Beaver is the Old one. Bionic is an LTS Version which is comparably more stable than Disco Dingo which has a shorter life term and as well as support.

Comment: Thank you for the information... I will have to look into that as searching for "Ubuntu 19.04" resulted in Disco Dingo and seeing that it is a major revision, I assume would be more stable. Maybe this oddity is because it is not a normal stream but is ubuntustudio, which I rely on heavily since I do a lot of media editing. Thank you for the advice.